# Linking C and R in Windows

Tags: c, r, windows

I am trying to Link R and C in windows while following the instructions on this web page

http://mcglinn.web.unc.edu/blog/linking-c-with-r-in-windows/

I have R, RTOOLS and TurboC4 all in separate folders in C drive. My system is 64bits but I have tried it on both 32 and 64 bit R.

I have written the following code in C

```
#include <R.h>

void hello(int *n)
 { int i;
    for(i=0; i<=*n; i++){
     Rprintf("hello, world!this is hell though I'm enjoying it\n");
     }
 }
```

and saved with name WORLD.C on separate file the path to which is 
   C:\TurboC4\TC\BIN

I have also written the following R code

```
hello2 <- function(n) {
.C("hello", as.integer(n))
 }

hello2(5)
```

and save it with name WORLD.R.

Now I have to prepare my window. I have downloaded RTools33.exe from here  https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

and set the environment variables manually through this command

```
PATH=c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;c:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\i386;
```

Then Reinstalled system

Before calling the C code in R I have to compile the C code in cmd. I write the following command to change the directory where WORLD.C is saved

```
cd C:\Users\TurboC4\TC\BIN
```

which is successful but when I try to compile

```
C:\Users\TurboC4\TC\BIN> R CMD SHLIB WORLD.c
```

I get the following error. " 'R' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable ". I have also tried to compile WORLD.C in C and got these two errors. "Unable to open #include R.h>" and "function Rprintf should have a prototype".

Setting Environment is a Problem 
I think this is where I am facing problem. I have checked that Rtools33.exe is compatible with R 3.2.x and later. But I am getting the same error on CMD.   I have tried different paths environments and have tried it with Different R versions like R- 3.2.2, R- 3.2.0, 2.15.3, 2.15.0.   But when I write

"install.packages("RTools33") in any of these R version, I got the following warning message

```
Warning in install.packages :package ‘RTools33’ is not available (for R version    
2.15.0)"
```

The reason for using different Rs is when you download RTOOLS folder there is a version file which says  "Rtools Collection 3.3.0.1959". So I think maybe it a compatibility issue.

There are some instructions on Github page 
https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Install-Rtools-for-Windows
"For installing Rtools, attention needs to be paid in a step where we can edit the system PATH so that the C++ compiler that is included in Rtools can be used by R. As indicated by the following step, we need to check this option (not manually edit the system PATH. Once the option is checked, system PATH would be edited to include important folders of Rtools by the installation process)."

So, I have uninstalled RTools and while reinstalling I have checked this option button as well and then retried but all in vein.

I have checked Sys.getenv('PATH') and got

```
c:\\\\\\\\Rtools\\\\\\\\gcc-4.6.3\\\\\\\\bin;c:\\\\\\\\RTools\\\\\\\\bin;
```

I have also tried by setting this path in 
    control pannel-> useraccountandfamilysafety->Useraccounts->change my
    environment variable
 and then creating new variable with above PATH. 
I am still not able to direct R to C++ compiler. Can anybody please figure out what is my mistake?

Answer (score -1):

This problem is now solved.  There was just a minor mistake of defining the environment variable. The correct definition is as follows.

```
c:\Rtools\bin;c:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin;c:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\i386;
```